# Changed directories in eclipse, project went all red

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, directory

I'm trying to correct the structure of an existing eclipse project, so I changed the src path to src/main/java and src/test/java.
the problem is that even after re importing the project, eclipse is acting not correctly.
It says : Cannot resolve XYZ as a Type.

I'm trying to make eclipse ignore the pattern main.java. it should start with org.xx.yy directly..

Screenshot :
[image: directory]

How can I fix it ?
Thank you.

Comment: have you revised the package declaration in the classes?

Comment: You can look at Problems tab and see what is the problem with your project. And write it in the question please.

Comment: done, thank you for yor comment.
fran : I must not change the declaration, because eclipse should ignore the main.java part of the package declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

**Option 1 : (Eclipse way)**

- Go to Project Explorer view:  Right Click Project -> Configure Build Path
- Go to **Source** tab and check the included source folder(s)
- If you find only ***ACT/src*** as included source, edit it and change to *ACT/src/main/java*

**Option 2 : (Maven way)**

- Right click Project -> Maven -> Update Project
- Project -> Clean

Comment: thanks, it says the folder src/main/java already exists
edit: i deleted the folder and then readded it after correcting the build path and it worked thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete the src from the sources.

Do the following.

1. Right click on your project > build path and click configure build path.
2. Click the sources tab and delete ACT/src.

NOTE: you should only have the following in your sources.

- ACT/src/main/java
- ACT/src/test/java
- ACT/src/main/resources
- ACT/src/test/resources

Comment: If you don't delete the src folder it will say "the folder already exists".

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the project, select Maven > Update Project...

Make sure these items are checked:

- Update project configuration from pom.xml
- Refresh workspace resources from local filesystem

Click OK.